# How to add child items to a Firebase "array"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning about Firebase by building a to-do application, and for adding items to a certain list, I'd like to find the list by its slug, and add an item to it, provided by the user. Currently, I have the following query:

```
database.ref('lists').orderByChild('slug').equalTo(listSlug).child('items').push({
    title: values.itemTitle
})
```

This produces the following error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__utils_firebase__.a.ref(...).equalTo(...).child is not a function
```

The parameters are correct, `listSlug` is what it is supposed to be, and `values` are what is supposed to be as well. Querying by finding the item with the given slug has worked for me when retrieving the list, but I can't seem to find how to add items to it.

EDIT:

Upon request, here is the database and an unsaved example of what I'd like to add:
[image: saving the world, one item at a time]

Comment: Can you share an example of your current database structure where this array is stored?

Comment: @Grimthorr, there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving data to the database using `push()`, `set()` or `update()` are methods of the [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) interface, which also provides further methods to retrieve data from the database.

Now, when calling `orderByChild()` or `equalTo()` methods on a `Reference`, a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) is returned instead. Unlike a `Reference`, a `Query` can only be used to retrieve data from the database.

In order to push data to the database, you will need to know the exact location of the array node within the database first, and create a `Reference` to it using `database.ref(...).child(...)`.

For example, if the array is located at `/lists/listId1/items`, you'd need to use:

```
database.ref('lists').child('listId1').child('items').push({
    title: values.itemTitle
})
```

Or, simply:

```
database.ref('lists/listId1/items').push({
    title: values.itemTitle
})
```

If you don't know the location of the node, you would need to query the database first to locate it. Or, if you have previously loaded data using a query, you can obtain the `Reference` from the results by using [`DataSnapshot#ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref) (or just [`DataSnapshot#key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) for the key), thereby negating the need to query for the location again before pushing.

Comment: So I'd have to look up the ID separately? Query the database based on the slug, get the ID and then push into items?

Comment: @zcserei That's correct, if you don't know the ID, you'd need to query the database first to locate it. If you've previously loaded the data using a query, you can obtain the key from the results by using [`DataSnapshot#key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key), and then store this in a variable for later use, therefore negating the need to query the database again for the key before adding a record. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have a solution based on your answer, clearing the difference between Reference and Query objects helped a lot.